# Dart/Flutter sockets connects on random port

Tags: android, flutter, sockets, dart

Modern programming is turning more and more frustrating. Trying to do a simple socket test app on Flutter (tested on Android). Code is simple and self explanatory:

```
 void Connect()
  {
    print("connecting...");
    Socket.connect("localhost", 80).then((Socket sock) {
      socket = sock;
      socket?.listen(dataHandler,
          onError: errorHandler,
          onDone: doneHandler,
          cancelOnError: false);
      socket?.write("GET / HTTP/1.1");
    }).catchError((Object e) {
      print("Unable to connect: $e");
    });
  }
```

Code throws exception. Output:

```
I/flutter (15930): connecting...
I/flutter (15930): Unable to connect: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 47244
```

The port is always different, why TF is that happening?

Comment: What would you expect to be running at port 80 on "localhost" of an Android device? Wouldn't you want to specify the IP address of the server that you want the app on the Android device to connect to?

Comment: Another question would be why you are trying to use `Socket` to do HTTP communication? There are `HttpClient` in `dart:io` and you can find multiple packages on pub.dev which makes HTTP/HTTPS communication easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port number in the error message is the local port and not the remote port. There are an issue about this problem here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/12693

In short, when connecting using TCP, you need two ports. One local which is open on your device and one remote which is the port open on the system you are trying to call. After a connection is established, the communication is going between this two port numbers.

So the error indicates that your server running on `localhost:80` is refusing the connection from your application. The local port number in the error message can often just be ignored since it is not really relevant to debug most issues.

Comment: Understood. Never saw error message before that states local port and not the one you are trying to connect. Thanks!

Comment: @Nanev Yeah, I have been burned by the same detail which is why I knew about the reported issue. :)